# gae python datastore query

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore

i m new to gae and python too, i m trying to build simple app using datastore in which script is as follows

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util

class Pincodes(db.Model):
  city = db.StringProperty()
  code = db.StringProperty()

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    q = Pincodes.all()
    q = q.filter("city =", "some_city")
    p = q.get()
    r = 'city: %s code: %s' % (pincode.city, pincode.code)
    self.response.out.write(r)
```

my script also contain usual def main() and if__name, im developing it step by step from simple hello world app shown in code.google docs and it worked fine, i hav uploaded sample pincode data containing 10 records to local datastore and its fine too but im not able to query and display it on webpage i tried self.response.out.write and the output is "city: code: " and not "city: mumbai code:400001" whats wrong with my script

Comment: *What* shows that? How are you doing that query? What code are you running? Where are you running it?

Comment: its sample app im creating on dev appserver, im querying it with methods like query.all and gql but it shows message i hav mentioned above, im running code which i evaluated from demo guestbook app and my gae sdk is 1.6.1 and python 2.5.4, im a new to it so you can help me write a sample script which i can use.

Comment: No. You did not answer my comment. **Show your code**.

Comment: i hav edited my question, hope u find it useful now.

Comment: Don't use print in a WSGI app. Use self.response.out.write.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
entity = q.get() # use get if you want one entity only  
r = 'city: %s code: %s' %(entity.city, entity.code)  
self.response.out.write(r)
```

instead of the print

edit:

```
 def get(self):
    q = Pincodes.all()
    q = q.filter("city =", "some_city")
    entity = q.get() # use get if you want one entity only  
    r = 'city: %s code: %s' %(entity.city, entity.code)  
    self.response.out.write(r)
```

edit2:

```
 def get(self):
    q = Pincodes.all()
    q = q.filter("city =", "some_city")
    entity = q.get() # use get if you want one entity only  
    if not entity:
        self.response.out.write('sorry no entities found')
    else:
        r = 'city: %s code: %s' %(entity.city, entity.code)  
        self.response.out.write(r)
```

Comment: tried ur answer but it is still not working , query is not happening.

Comment: i edited my answer. try to copy paste the code and see if that gives you the expected result

Comment: now its showing "AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'has_key'"  do u hav any idea what it means?

Comment: can you post the whole traceback?

Comment: tried it again error is gone but it is showing "city:  code: "and it is not showing answer to the query. should i post my question again.

Comment: im not getting what u r trying to tell me , my script is same as i wrote above except from def get(self) u told me to paste ur code and i did it but output is "city: code: " and not the query answer

Comment: what you are trying to do is really simple and what im asking you is pretty simple too. 
is there a Pincodes entity in your datastore with a city and code property set?
i think you should start reading the documentation because it does not look you have the right knowledge right now.

Comment: @ aschmid00, i hav read d docs and modified my script and yes i hav pincode entity in my datastore containing 10 records of various city and respective pincode but d problem is still same it shows "city: code:" instead of city: mumbai code:400001, i wanna ask u if there is  something trigger to start before querying in app engine

Comment: can you see the if you browse the datastore console at /_ah/admin ? did you change the appid since you created the entites? i added an edit2, try that one and see what the output is.

Comment: hi aschmid00 sorry for late reply im on some other project, yes i see d records when browsing datastore console at admin and i havent changed my appid. tried edit2 but d output is same.

Comment: can you upload your app to github or somewhere where its possible to download the code?

Comment: yes i hv uploaded my app on code.google.com here is the link  http://code.google.com/p/pincodesearchindia/downloads/list  , i hv also uploaded pin.csv file which include records from my local datastore i hv uploaded using bulkloader and thanks for ur support.

Comment: you did not upload the code that is failing, instead you upload a handler that returns a string. you did not upload any csv file with data. and you did not tell how you load the csv entitites into the datastore. sry but i cant't help you like this.

Comment: im really sorry i accidently uploaded files from other folder i created to learn data models in python, now i uploaded d code that is failing but im not able to upload main.py so uploaded main.py.txt which contain code as it is in main.py . sorry again

Comment: how do you populate your database? do you have a bulkloader.yaml? what command do you use with the csv file. you really need to start telling everything you do because thats the only way to help you.

Comment: to populate db i use bulkloader. first i created config file for mapping of data model, i will upload it to d same address given above and text file conataning command.

Comment: i need the command you use. i want a step by step of what you are doing because this is a simple thing you are trying to do but its failing somewhere and if you don't tell me every single thing you do i cant figure out where it goes wrong.

Comment: i hv uploaded bulkloader process.txt which contains step by step info of what i did and the command i ran to upload data and d app is developed step by step from simple hello world app

Comment: so i know the solution but im kinda pissed with you because you have the answer posted on top but the code you use in the uploaded file is not what i posted in my answer. read my answer another 50 times and if you cant understand or copy paste then i think there is no hope for you. (hint check how you use variables in your code.)